Generic networking layer in Swift
I've been learning iOS for 5 months with no previous experience in programming language so I'm a newbie. I'm learning how to create a more robust and scalable networking layer in Swift. So far so good i can understand what is going on in here however I'm struggling to refactor my code to accept both POST and GET requests. I have received authorization key for my POST request but I have no idea how to do it. Please give me some guidance
protocol HTTPDataDownloader {
    func fetchData <T: Decodable>(as type: T.Type, endpoint: String) async throws -> T
}

extension HTTPDataDownloader {
    func fetchData <T: Decodable>(as type: T.Type, endpoint: String) async throws -> T {
        guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else {
            throw APIError.requestFailed(description: "Invalid URL")
        }
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
            throw APIError.requestFailed(description: "Request failed")
        }
        guard httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
            throw APIError.invalidStatusCode(statuscode: httpResponse.statusCode)
        }
        do {
            return try JSONDecoder().decode(type, from: data)
        } catch {
            throw error as? APIError ?? .unknownError(error: error)
        }
    }
}

class CommentsDataService: HTTPDataDownloader {
    private let urlString = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments"
    
    func fetchComments() async throws -> [Comments] {
        return try await fetchData(as: [Comments].self, endpoint: urlString)
    }
}
    
@Observable
class CommentsViewModel {
    var comments = [Comments]()
    var errorMessage: String?
    
    private let service: CommentsDataService
    
    init(service: CommentsDataService) {
        print("DEBUG: did init")
        self.service = service
        Task { await fetchComments() }
    }
    
    @MainActor
    func fetchComments() async {
        do {
            self.comments = try await service.fetchComments()
        } catch {
            guard let error = error as? APIError else { return }
            self.errorMessage = error.customDescription
        }
    }
}


struct Comments: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let email: String
    let body: String
}

enum APIError: Error {
    case invalidData
    case jsonParsingFailure
    case requestFailed(description: String)
    case invalidStatusCode(statuscode: Int)
    case unknownError(error: Error)
    
    var customDescription: String {
        switch self {
        case .invalidData:
            return "Invalid data"
        case .jsonParsingFailure:
            return "Failed to parse JSON"
        case .requestFailed(let description):
            return "Request failed: \(description)"
        case .invalidStatusCode(let statuscode):
            return "Invalid status code \(statuscode)"
        case .unknownError(let error):
            return "An unknown error occured \(error)"
        }
    }
}


I just edited my post. i'll ask the second question tomorrow

It's unclear if you already succeed in doing a simple POST request according to your Web API needs. If not, start by doing that, then later only try to factorize/use generic. But until you can't do a specific sample, don't try to generalize, it's too early, especially in your learning curve.

A possible way is to add an optional parameter post. If it's nil a GET request is performed otherwise a POST request processing the given dictionary. The dictionary is mapped to the key1=value1&key2=value2 syntax and converted to Data.
The code takes advantage of the fact that the default httpMethod of  URLRequest is GET
protocol HTTPDataDownloader {
    func fetchData <T: Decodable>(as type: T.Type, endpoint: String, post: [String:Any]?) async throws -> T
}


extension HTTPDataDownloader {
    func fetchData <T: Decodable>(as type: T.Type, endpoint: String, post: [String:Any]? = nil) async throws -> T {
        guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else {
            throw APIError.requestFailed(description: "Invalid URL")
        }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url) // default method is GET
        if let post {
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            let body = Array(post.keys).map { "\($0)=\(post[$0]!)" }.joined(separator:"&")
            request.httpBody = Data(body.utf8)
        }
        
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
        
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
            throw APIError.requestFailed(description: "Request failed")
        }
        guard httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
            throw APIError.invalidStatusCode(statuscode: httpResponse.statusCode)
        }
        do {
            return try JSONDecoder().decode(type, from: data)
        } catch {
            throw error as? APIError ?? .unknownError(error: error)
        }
    }
}

And you should add a case jsonDecodingError. The decoding error is not unknown.

The method you chose - URLSession.shared.data doesn't allow you to customize much. So you need to use one of the other numerous methods of the same object. The closest to the one you used is another data(for:delegate:) method, which accepts a different argument - URLRequest, where you can specify method:
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.method = "POST"

